# Linux: Start daemon on connected USB-serial dongle

Tags: linux, usb, boot, udev, systemd

On my Linux (Angstrom distro on BeagleBone Black) I have a USB dongle which presents as  a serial port and per default is available as `/dev/ttyUSB0`

I want to start a daemon, which will connect to the serial port and make it available as a socket. I have the code for this USB-to-socket bridge and it works when started by hand.

I want it to start automatically whenever the system boots, supposing the USB dongle is plugged in. How should I do this?

Attempts so far:

1. systemd: I created a systemd service with conditions `After: remote-fs.target` and `After:syslog.target` , but (it seems) the USB dongle is not ready at that point and the startup of the daemon fails.

   Are there other systemd `targets` or `services` to condition to, so that the daemon is started only when the udev has finished installing devices and the network is ready?
2. udev: I created a udev rule like

   KERNEL=="ttyUSB?", RUN+="/path/to/daemon.sh"

   which executes successfully. But the daemon (which is started as a background process with a "&" within that script) seems not to execute. Also it seems to be frowned upon, to fork long running processes from udev rules.

**What is the correct way to do it?**

Comment: I had a similar problem a while ago, this blog article helps me a lot (since it's almost exactly what you are trying to do).

[Proper(-ish) way to start long-running systemd service on udev event (device hotplug)](http://blog.fraggod.net/2012/06/16/proper-ish-way-to-start-long-running-systemd-service-on-udev-event-device-hotplug.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reference, it now works!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Create a udev rule like

```
# cat /etc/udev/rules.d/95-serialdaemon.rules
KERNEL=="ttyUSB0", TAG+="systemd", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}="serialdaemon.service"
```

Create a systemd service like

```
# cat /lib/systemd/system/serialdaemon.service
[Unit]
Description=USB serial to socket bridge
After=remote-fs.target
After=syslog.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/mnt/serialdaemon.sh
```

Create the executable file

```
# cat /mnt/serialdaemon.sh
#!/bin/sh
date +%F-%T >> /var/log/serialdaemon.log
/usr/local/serialdaemon/serialdaemon -serial /dev/ttyUSB0 -port 15789 -baud 38400 >> /var/log/serialdaemon.log 2>&1
date +%F-%T >> /var/log/serialdaemon.log
```

Comment: You can just mark your own anwser as "accepted", since it's the right solution for your problem. Nothing wrong about it...

Comment: The file locations could be improved though: the `.service` file should be placed in `/etc/systemd/system` and the executable in `/usr/local/bin`.

Answer (score 5):

Since the link in my further comment seems to solve this problem, here is the solution for using udev for starting a daemon when a certain usb device is plugged in:

[Proper(-ish) way to start long-running systemd service on udev event (device hotplug)](http://blog.fraggod.net/2012/06/16/proper-ish-way-to-start-long-running-systemd-service-on-udev-event-device-hotplug.html)

Comment: Accepting your answer so you get the points. Mine's there just for (my own) reference.

Comment: This link gives workable solution, but in case this link gets broken in future, please also copy-paste the gist of contents from that link in your answer. Of course, you will need to give due credit by mentioning the original link.

Comment: @anishsane Sorry for that, you're correct. This was one of my first posts on SO, if I've written the answer today, I would have done that. I will add a summary of the solution provided in the link if I have some spare time.

Comment: No issues. I was just saying it as a general guideline... Besides, this helped me recently :)